# PHP code is working with MySQL but not in LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lamp

I am new to web development. I recently installed LAMP stack and was trying to connect my PHP code to MySQL which established a connection and created a database (All the code was written in a directory in opt/lampp/htdocs).

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";                 // specifying the port number seems necessary
$username = "akshay";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "sys";
try {
  //valid database needs to be mentioned
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);       
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully<br>";

  $sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDBPDO";
  // use exec() because no results are returned
  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo "Database created successfully<br>";

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection Error: " . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

And it worked fine. But when I proceeded further to create a table in my database, the server gave an error:

**Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myDBPRO'**

I later found out that MySQL was running independently and not in the lamp stack. (i.e. it always showed "ok" whenever I ran `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`  whereas Apache and ProFTPD showed "already running". I was not able to open myphpadmin either).
To connect MySQL to the LAMP, I stopped MySQL:

`sudo service mysql stop`

And then restarted my lamp stack: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` (This time MySQL was connected as it showed already connected when I ran the command again and I was able to open pyphpadmin too.) So, I tried to run my code again but this time, it would not even connect. It gave the following error:

```
Connection Error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'akshay'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have the following doubts:

1. How was my code initially working if MYSQL was not connected to LAMP stack?
2. Why was the created database not present in PHPMyAdmin?
3. How to make MySQL work with LAMP?

(Forgive me if something is too obvious, I am quite new to this.)

Comment: By any chance did you already have MySQL installed on the machine before you installed LAMP? Maybe you have got two different instances of MySQL running? You need to check that. From what you've described, that sounds like the most likely reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I did install mysql earlier. But I checked in /usr/lib and there is only one mysql directory present(which I think indicates that there is only one version of  MySQL installed).

Comment: what linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ok thanks. And how exactly did you install the LAMP stack? e.g. via some apt-get command(s)? Or another method?

Comment: I installed each of them separately, I first installed apache via ```sudo apt-get install apache2``` and then mysql via ```sudo apt-get install mysql-server``` and then ```mysql_secure_installation```(I think I had mysql before but followed the steps just to be safe) . I can't find php installation in my history. Then I ran ```sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-7.4.7-0-installer.run``` after installing xampp setup.

Comment: Did you then also execute that `.run` file after you altered it with chmod? I ask because, if you installed mysql via apt-get, and then installed xampp as well separate via a binary installer, this suggests you've probably got two instances of mysql installed (because xampp will install mysql as part of the install). You need to _either_ install all the components separately via apt-get, _or_ use a pre-built full-stack installer such as xampp. Don't do both!

Comment: P.S. even if you use the packages / apt-get method, you don't have to actually install everything separately. Ubuntu already has a pre-made routine for doing this - see https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-lamp-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-apache-mysql-php . I think you won't get phpMyAdmin with that setup, but even that isn't hard to sort out if you need it - see https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04/ . Or you could just install the MySQL Workbench desktop admin tool instead to administer your databases.

Comment: I did run that fiile. How can I figure out if I have two instances of mysql installed and how can I correct it?

Comment: There are probably two different mysql executables on your hard disk. But I think your description of what you've done, and the behaviour you're seeing, is sufficient to be fairly sure that's what is happening

Comment: I think the best solution is probably to uninstall the XAMPP one and just go with the packaged version

Comment: Thanks a lot! I uninstalled XAMPP and installed LAMP as mentioned in the article mentioned by you and everything is working perfectly now. New database is created in phpmadmin and tables are created perfectly.